# How do I view "Signature hash algorithm" in C# certificate callback?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I have a server that uses the following certificate for SSL/TLS communications:

[image: Cert viewer]

In my C# code, I use a custom certificate validation callback to view the properties of this certificate programmatically, like so:

```
private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    // Certificate2 is better than Certificate1, right?
    X509Certificate2 cert = (X509Certificate2)certificate;            

    Console.WriteLine("Certificate Subject   : " + cert.Subject);
    Console.WriteLine("Certificate Issuer    : " + cert.Issuer);
    // So on and so forth...
}
```

However, my problem is that I cannot seem to see that "Signature hash algorithm" property. `cert.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName` returns `RSASSA-PSS`, and

`new System.Security.Cryptography.Oid(cert.GetKeyAlgorithm()).FriendlyName)`

returns simply `RSA`. None of these properties seem to give me that "sha256" property that I see in the GUI. How do I return that property?

Edit: I found [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2048/difference-between-signature-algorithm-and-signature-hash-algorithm-in-x-509) related question on Cryptography.SE that explains that Microsoft's certificate viewer GUI is a little wonky and off-standard, but if that's the case then I want to be wonky too. I want to know how to report "sha256" the same way that the GUI does.

Update 08/13: Viewed from another perspective, when I use the command

```
certutil.exe -dump cert.cer
```

An excerpt of the result:

```
Signature Algorithm:
    Algorithm ObjectId: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 RSASSA-PSS
    Algorithm Parameters:
    0000  30 34 a0 0f 30 0d 06 09  60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02
    0010  01 05 00 a1 1c 30 1a 06  09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01
    0020  01 08 30 0d 06 09 60 86  48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05
    0030  00 a2 03 02 01 20
            2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha256 (sha256NoSign)
            05 00
            1.2.840.113549.1.1.8 mgf1
                2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha256 (sha256NoSign)
                05 00
            0x20 (32)
```

I sure wish I knew how to find those OIDs (the sha256 ones) for myself... without resorting to parsing the output of an actual certutil command.

Comment: I believe you can get the algorithm via the `algID` member of a `CRYPT_OID_INFO` received by calling `CryptFindOIDInfo`, but I don't see any access to that from the BCL.  You will probably have to p/Invoke.

Comment: Or you can parse it out yourself using some ASN.1 library or you can use BouncyCastle which could read it (but I don't know for sure)

Comment: @pepo I'm really hoping to avoid the use of third party libraries such as BouncyCastle if at all possible. It'd even rather P/Invoke than use BouncyCastle.

Comment: P/Invoke it is then :)

Answer (score 0):

From your DER bytes, these are signature algorithms.

```
2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 08
```

I know these are signature algorithms.
But, I don't know how to analyse these bytes.

I presume that last byte means the hash algorithm.
I tested with openssl, last byte changed from 0b->0c->0d,
when I generated a certificate with sha256, sha384, sha5512.
Please let me know, when you have figured it out.